# How to get the commands and table that deadlocked in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to get the deadlocked tables/column, and commands that locked the table/column. Has a way?

Comment: If you're getting an actual deadlock (i.e. an ORA-00060 error is being raised), then a deadlock trace file would be generated which has the information that would be required to identify that information.  Do you actually have a deadlock trace file?

Answer (score -1):

The Oracle view v$lock contains details of all locks at that time.

The ID1 value will map to DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_ID.

You will need to be granted SELECT on these views if you do not have DBA access.

More details [here](http://www.orafaq.com/node/854) and [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_find_blocking_sessions.htm)